# Fancybox form ajax submit, only one ajax request

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, fancybox

I've a question about ajax submitting.

I have a html form

```
<div style="display:none">
    <form id="myform" method="post" action="">
        <input type="text" id="name" />
        <input type="submit" id="sbmt" />
    </form>
</div>
```

And button to open the fancybox:

```
<a id="sbtfancybox" href="#myform">
    <input type="button" value="Add new" 
           onClick="defineFancybox();" />
</a>
```

And i define a fancybox with jquery:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function defineFancybox() {
        $('#sbtfancybox').fancybox({
            //...some json parameters
        });

        $('#myform').submit(function() {//the main problem is here
             //....calling an ajax
             return false;
        });
    }
</script>
```

My question is that how to do `$('#myform').submit(..)` that the submit always is called once, not that if i open fancybox the first time, the `$('#myform').submit()` is called once, if i open the fancybox the second time, the `$('#myform').submit()` is called twice, if i open the fancybox the third time then `$('#myform').submit()` is called tree times etc.

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

jQuery event handlers don't override each other, even in the case where you're binding the same function again. Every time you call this code:

```
$('#myform').submit(function() {//the main problem is here
    //....calling an ajax
    return false;
});
```

another event handler gets added. Since that code is in the function that is called when you click on your button, the first click results in one event handler. The second click adds another one, so you now have two. The third click adds another, so you have three...

Since the form doesn't appear to be dynamically created you can just bind the single event handler when the page loads:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#myform').submit(function() {
        //....calling an ajax
        return false;
    });
});
```

Then move it out of the `defineFancybox()` function.

If you absolutely *have* to keep the event handler binding inside that function, then you can use the [`.off()`](http://api.jquery.com/off/) (or [`.unbind()`](http://api.jquery.com/unbind/) if you're using a version prior to 1.7) function to remove any existing event handlers before binding the new one:

```
$('#myform').off('submit').submit(function() {
    //....calling an ajax
    return false;
});
```

Comment: I need several fancyboxes for editing many records in a table, so onClick="defFP"; is useful.

Comment: @user1929552 Is it always the same form, though? If it is then you only need the one submit handler and you don't need to bind it inside the function that creates/initialises the fancy box. However, if you do want/need to keep it inside that function, I've added some additional information that would allow you to do that.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried with `.one()` handler:

```
$('#myform').one('submit', function() {//This will make it submitted once
    //....calling an ajax
    return false;
});
```

Comment: Great! this helped. This would be even greater if you accept it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like

```
    $('#myform').unbind('submit');
    $('#myform').bind('submit',function() {//the main problem is here
         //....calling an ajax
         return false;
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You may try the following

```
$("#myform").each(function(i) {
    var handler = i.on("submit", function() {
        handler.stop();
        // do stuff
    });
    // other stuff
});
```

Comment: This code won't work. The first argument passed to the function passed to `.each()` is the index (so an integer), which won't have an `.on()` function.